# Possible to modify a List while iterating through it?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following:

```
foreach (var depthCard in depthCards)
{
    var card = InternalGetCard(db, depthCard.CardId);
    var set = InternalGetSet(db, (int)card.ParentSetId);
    var depthArray = InternalGetDepthArrayForCard(db, set.SetId);
    foreach (var cardToUpdate in set.Cards)
    {
        // do stuff
        SaveChanges(db);
        // since I already took care of it here, remove from depthCards
        depthCards.Remove(depthCardToUpdate);
    }
}
```

This isn't working though because I'm modifying the collection in the middle of a loop. Is there some type of collection that does allow this type of access?

I don't want to `ToList()` the `depthCards` because I already have them and I *want* to modify that list as I'm iterating. Is this possible?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's possible, the trick is to iterate backwards:

```
for (int i = depthCards.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (depthCards[i] == something) { // condition to remove element, if applicable
     depthCards.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can iterate backwards with a `for`-loop

```
for (int i = depthCards.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    depthCards.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

or if you just want to remove items on a condition, use `List.RemoveAll`:

```
depthCardToUpdate.RemoveAll(dc => conditionHere);
```

Comment: Could always add a `Where()` statement in before doing the `ForEach()` to narrow down the results before removing them, if its a conditional removal.

Comment: @Bob.: No, because then it wouldn't be a `List<T>` anymore but a `IEnumerable<T>` which doesn't support the `List.ForEach` method. You could only use `foreach` then, but then it's not possible to modify the list in the loop.

Comment: Isn't that what `ToList()` is for?

Comment: No, ToList creates a new list. So you,re doubling the memory consumption(in  the best case).

Comment: The second code snippet still would potentially crash as it is forbidden to modify the underlying collection while iterating with ForEach. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Comment: @Vringar: You're right, might not work. Docs say: "Modifying the underlying collection in the body of the Action<T> delegate is not supported and causes undefined behavior." Deleted that approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom enumerator that handles this for you. I did this once and it was a bit tricky but worked after some finesse.

See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28963/Custom-Enumerators