# How do I delete multiple records in database using EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, sql-delete

I want to delete according to the `AdvertId` in it, not according to the ID. I find `AdvertId` but I'm stuck on deletion. I am using CQRS structure. My `Repository` and `IRepository` folders are located separately. In the controller part, I am doing the transaction by finding the `advertId`.

```
public class Advert_CategoryPropertyDetailJunctionDeleteHandler : 
        IRequestHandler<Advert_CategoryPropertyDetailJunctionDelete, ApiResponse>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _repo;

    public Advert_CategoryPropertyDetailJunctionDeleteHandler(IUnitOfWork repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public async Task<ApiResponse> Handle(Advert_CategoryPropertyDetailJunctionDelete 
    request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var mapped = await 
        _repo.AdvertCategoryPropertyDetailJunctions.GetAllAsync(request.predicate);

        if (mapped == null)
            return new ErrorApiResponse(ResultMessage.NotDeletedUser);

        await _repo.AdvertCategoryPropertyDetailJunctions.DeleteAllAsync((Advert_CategoryPropertyDetailJunction) mapped);

        return new SuccessApiResponse();
    }
}
```

IRrepository:

```
Task<IEnumerable> DeleteAllAsync(T entity);
```

Repository;

```
public async Task<IEnumerable> DeleteAllAsync(T entity)
{
    Context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return (IEnumerable)entity;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete multiple rows in Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960215/how-do-i-delete-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 8):

This feature is introduced in EF7 described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates).

It would look like:

```cs
await context.Customers
    .Where(x => x.AdvertId == advertIdToDelete)
    .ExecuteDeleteAsync();
```

Comment: Is any additional package needed for this? I'm in .NET 7 and EF Core 7 and ExecuteDeleteAsync or ExecuteUpdateAsync are not available to me.

Edit: forget it, working after adding Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately EF Core doesn't support these operations. You have to fetch them all and then delete.

```
var entities = _repository.GetAllByAdvertId(advertId);
_repository.Delete(entities);
```

and repository implementation

```
public async Task<IEnumerable> DeleteAllAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        foreach(var entity of entities){
            Context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return (IEnumerable)entity;

    }
```

but this solution is not optimal for large data sets.

If you have a large data set, you can use `Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore` package.

```
context.Customers
    .Where(x => x.AdvertId == AdvertId)
    .DeleteFromQuery();
```

In this way, the query will be executed in the database and you won't need to fetch all data in the local context to perform this operation.

See examples [Batch Operations Methods](https://entityframework-extensions.net/overview#batch-operations-methods)