# My for loop isn't looping over as many times as I want

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm stumped on this right now, and I don't know why it's happening. In this class, I have a function that loops over all the numbers before a decimal point to cull extra zeroes off the end, and does it for the numbers after the decimal point as well. The second part (removing the extra zeroes before the decimal point) works fine, but the first part (removing the extra zeroes after the decimal point) doesn't.

I have to call the function multiple times for it to cull all of the extra zeroes on the right-hand end of the number, and I don't know why. I suspect it might have something to do with checking whether a byte is == 0, but I'm not sure yet.

FYI: The function is called in the constructor at the very end.

```
public class GiantNumber
{
    //constructor and some other functions...

    public bool IsNegative { get; }
    public bool HasDecimal { get; }
    public List<byte> NumbersBeforeDecimal;
    public List<byte> NumbersAfterDecimal;

    public void CullZeroes()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumbersBeforeDecimal.Count; i++)
        {
            byte number = NumbersBeforeDecimal[i];

            if (number == 0)
            {
                NumbersBeforeDecimal.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = NumbersAfterDecimal.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            byte number = NumbersAfterDecimal[i];

            if (number == 0)
            {
                NumbersAfterDecimal.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is `NumbersBeforeDecimal.RemoveAt(i)` removes the current element, while `i` is still incremented. So the next iteration would check not the next element but the one after it.

Comment: Loop backwards!  [Possible to modify a List while iterating through it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767161/possible-to-modify-a-list-while-iterating-through-it)  (dupe)

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense! I kind of want to only remove the zeroes at the beginning (before there are significant figures), so do you have any suggestions to this?

Edit: What if I just leave the iterator in the for loop blank? Edit #2: It works if I leave it blank!

Comment: The dumb way is something like `while (NumbersBeforeDecimal.Count > 1 && NumbersBeforeDecimal[0] == 0) NumbersBeforeDecimal.RemoveAt(0);`. Better way is to find index of the first non-zero and then remove entire range from 0 to that index. The best way is not to store big numbers that way at all.

Comment: The reason I want to store big numbers this way is because I want to have an equivalent to BigInteger but with decimal values; in fact, I'm using two BigIntegers to do operations. I don't really care too much about performance here since this is just a hobby project in which I want to calculate Euler's Number to as precise of a number as I can.

Comment: You can store your number as `BigInteger` value and `int` exponent, so that `x = n * 10^-e`. Then multiplication of your numbers would be simply multiplication of `BigInteger`s and addition of exponents, and addition would be addition of `BigInteger`s where one of the values is multiplied by the difference between exponents.

Comment: BTW, there’s existing [BigRational](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/bcl/blob/master/Libraries/BigRational/BigRationalLibrary/BigRational.cs) implementation, so you may want to use it.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the BigRational post! I will definitely be using that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do that this way at all. RemoveAt is O(n), that means, that removing 10M digits would take roughly half an hour. It is about half an hour more than is really needed, as it can be done in miliseconds. You can remove the whole range in one step:

```
int j = 0;
while (j < NumbersBeforeDecimal.Count 
        && NumbersBeforeDecimal[j] == 0)
{
    ++j;
}
NumbersBeforeDecimal.RemoveRange(0, j);
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that RemoveRange exists, I will definitely use it more.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out with the help of Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp; since I'm deleting the index and iterating over the next one, I'm skipping an index every time I loop. If I leave the iterator blank:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumbersBeforeDecimal.Count; )
{
    //stuff
}
```

It won't skip over lines! This could be a better idea compared to iterating backwards when you want simpler code (in my case it's a lot better).

Comment: This is equal to `while(0 < NumbersBeforeDecimal.Count)`

Comment: Yes, yes it is. That would be simpler.

Comment: I think the accurate title for this post is 'My for loop isn't executing as many times as I want.'

Computers do what you tell them. Exactly what you tell them. Nothing less.
What you want is sometimes completely different.

Comment: Yes, that would be a more accurate title; I will change it.